# What is the rate of recharge for the Divine Blessing?

Tags: genshin-impact

I've hit the limit of my divine blessing this week.

I was next to the statue and it was empty. Didn't think I used it that much, and didn't hit the limit again after. Was weird.

But it sparks the question for me: How does the statue's blessing regen? Is it an amount per minute? And at what rate?

Comment: You can also configure how much the statue heals when you're near it. The default is 70% of characters HP. Besides having a low treshold here, you can still heal your characters fully by entering the "Statues Blessing"-menu when interacting with it and then clicking the desired characters.

Comment: Yeah thats one of the firsts thing i did. Put it to 100%. Wonder why its even a choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on multiple sources it takes 25 minutes for the statue Healing Power to fully recharge. Since this number is referenced by players that have reached different amounts of maximum charge (the total charge is based on the number of unlocked Statues), it is also quite believable that the recharge rate is percentage based instead of a fixed value.

The wiki claims that

> Restorative Power is used to heal characters and **regenerates itself at a rate of 1% of the maximum Restorative Power per 15 seconds in real time**, even while the game is paused (always fully restored in 25 minutes). The maximum Restorative Power is 5,000 × the number of Statues of the Seven that the player has unlocked.

Judging on empirical data, this seems to be accurate.